# What is this succulent with dark green paired ovate leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

What is the name of the following plant?

[image]

Comment: From the photo, it looks like a succulent, so I added that tag and updated the title. Please feel free to remove the tag if I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: What does the bottom of the leaf look like?  Is it greyish?

Comment: Does this plant have truly paired leaves? On the picture it almost looks like one leave of each pair is smaller than the other.

Could it be a Peperomia sp.? Perhaps a Peperomia orba?

Comment: @KlausAlexanderSeistrup, I believe you're close. Consider Peperomia obtusifolia as an answer.

Comment: @Brenn I believe you're right, it does indeed look like a P. obtusifolia.

Comment: @KlausAlexanderSeistrup Yup. You should post an official answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plant is a *Peperomia*, most likely a *Peperomia obtusifolia*.

[Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia_obtusifolia):

> Peperomia obtusifolia (baby rubberplant or pepper face) is a species of flowering plant in the family Piperaceae, native to Florida, Mexico and the Caribbean. It is an evergreen perennial growing to 25 cm (10 in) tall and broad, with cupped leathery leaves and narrow spikes of white flowers up to 12 cm (5 in) long.

[Peperomia Care](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/peperomia/growing-peperomia-houseplants.htm)

[image]

Comment: Nice edit, @Brenn!

Comment: I took the liberty since I too learned here recently, (I'm new here too), that the community appreciates a little more than just the name. And now we both know! ;)

Comment: Yes, that's great. I admire what you do. I'll try to be more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is a Crassula Lactea, we have one that looks very similar to this! I'd post a photo with my answer but I just joined and can't figure out how to post a photo with my questions or answers

Comment: There are Instructions for including photographs at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post if you're on a desktop PC or Mac. For an Android phone, see http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/989/22. Thanks, and welcome to the site.